# ERROR: syntax error at or near "TABLE" LINE 5: SELECT * FROM TABLE(str_common_utils.splitstr(p_...)

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_builder.sql_or_builder (v_field_name text, p_string text, v_operator text DEFAULT '=', p_delimiter text DEFAULT ',') RETURNS varchar AS $body$
DECLARE

        cur_fields CURSOR FOR
            SELECT * FROM TABLE(str_common_utils.splitstr(p_string, p_delimiter));
        v_sql varchar(4000) := '';

BEGIN
        v_sql := v_sql || ' (';
        FOR r_field IN cur_fields loop
            -- FOR DEBUG
            -- dbms_output.put_line(r_field.column_value);
            v_sql := v_sql || v_field_name || ' ' || v_operator || ' ''' ||
                     r_field.column_value || '''';
            v_sql := v_sql || ' or ';
        END LOOP;

        v_sql := substr(v_sql, 1, length(v_sql) - 4);
        v_sql := v_sql || ') ';

        -- FOR DEBUG
        -- dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
        RETURN v_sql;
    END;

$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
 STABLE;
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM str_common_utils.splitstr(p_string, p_delimiter)`

Answer (score 0):

That `TABLE` keyword in

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(str_common_utils.splitstr(p_string, p_delimiter));
```

does not exist. Just omit the `TABLE()` decoration around the function call. If you want a decoration, use `FROM ROWS FROM (str_common_utils.splitstr(p_string, p_delimiter))`.

Answer (score 0):

the `table()` operator is not necessary in Postgres to use set returning functions, so you just need:

```
  cur_fields CURSOR FOR
     SELECT * FROM str_common_utils.splitstr(p_string, p_delimiter);
```

---

But the whole function is way more complicated than it needs to be. As far as I can tell you can simplify it to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_or_builder(v_field_name text, p_string text, v_operator text DEFAULT '=', p_delimiter text DEFAULT ',') 
  RETURNS text
AS 
$body$
  select concat('(', string_agg(format('%I = %L', v_field_name, r.column_value), ' OR '), ')')
  from unnest(string_to_array(p_string, p_delimiter)) as r(column_value);
$body$
language sql
immutable;
```

e.g.

````
select sql_or_builder('some_name', 'one,two,three');
sql_or_builder                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------
(some_name = 'one' OR some_name = 'two' OR some_name = 'three')
```
````